# Web Parts from site are missing

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, moss2007-security

I was working on my sharePoint 2007(MOSS) Portal. I accessed a site and did  my reguler task. After some time when I check the webparts from the site page are missing. The Whole page is empty.. While I can see the navigation links only on site tab.. Please let me know Y this issue has occurred And I need to find a solution.

Comment: Can you give us more info? May b you didn't save or publish the page (?)

Answer (score 0):

Is the page published? Are you using the same user account for edit/display? Try adding ?contents=1 at the end of the URL and see if the parts are ACTUALLY on the page.

Also check the logs - ULS Log specifically.

David Sterling
davidmsterling.blogspot.com
www.sterling-consulting.com